# Runtime error when submitting to Kattis c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I solved this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/apaxiaaans) in c++ and it worked fine using the sample inputs. However, when I submit the code to Kattis, it's saying that I have a runtime error.

Right now I am not sure what to do since, my code works fine using the sample inputs. Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(){
    std::ifstream input_file;
    std::string file_path, user_input;
    cin >> file_path;
    input_file.open(file_path);

    if (!input_file) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        input_file >> user_input;
        input_file.close();

    };
    std::string answer;
    answer = user_input[0];
    for(int i=1; i < user_input.size(); i++){
        if(user_input[i] != user_input[i-1]){
            answer += user_input[i];
        }
    }
    cout << answer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `answer = user_input[0];` maybe user input is an empty string. You probably should return if the string is empty.

Comment: ***it's saying that I have a runtime error*** That information may help. Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Are you sure the site that you're using requires you to read in a file name and then open the corresponding file? As far as I can tell, you just have to read in the input from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Like most coding challenge judges, Kattis will always send the entirety of the input data to your program via stdin, not a filename.

In this particular challenge, the input is simple: a one line string of lowercase alphabetical characters. In other challenges, you'll often have to loop over multiple lines, parse numbers from strings and split on whitespace as well.

It might not matter on such a simple problem, but your algorithm also suffers from [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Use a `stringstream` so that appends are O(1) instead of O(n) with `+=`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::cin >> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || s[i] != s[i-1]) {
            ss << s[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
}
```

When speed matters, the following is a simple competitive coding skeleton, not considered good practice for application development:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

    // solve
}
```